# HTML Ordered lists (ol) with Arabic numbers

Tags: html, internationalization, arabic

How can I get arabic numbers (not numerals) in my ordered lists?

So instead of 1, 2, 3... I need ...١ ٢ ٣

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I tried it here http://jsfiddle.net/e2Gs7/ by using `ol {list-style: arabic-indic;}​` But i don't know if it's standard CSS...

Comment: You are right. Mozilla provides an own type: `-moz-arabic-indic`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/list-style-type

Comment: It’s “standard” in the sense of being part of the [CSS3 Lists and Counters draft] (http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-lists/), but not in the sense of being commonly implemented.

Answer (score -3):

Include the numbers (as such, or as character references like `&#x660;`) into the list item contents, and either use CSS to prevent browser-generated numbers (`list-style-type: none`) or, better, use markup other than `ul`, e.g. a `div` for each item and them items wrapped (if necessary) inside an outer `div`.

Depending on the server software used, you might be able to generate the numbers automatically.