# How can you change a list from using Arabic numbers to uppercase letters using HTML?

Tags: html

How can you change a list from using Arabic numbers to uppercase letters using HTML?

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I don't quite understand your question.

Comment: Please provide example of actual output and desired output to help us understand better.

Comment: Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377118/html-ordered-lists-ol-with-arabic-numbers/9377356

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried below:

```
<ol type="A">
```

For more details on options you have on ordered list:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists_ordered.asp